# Running sum in a pandas pivot table (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'publisher': ['facebook', 'facebook', 'facebook', 'google', 'google', 'google'],
          'month_leadgen': ['2019-01', '2019-01', '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-02', '2019-03'],
         'month_payment': ['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-03'],
         'revenue': [60, 25, 45, 85, 90, 60]})
```

I created a pivot table:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['publisher', 'month_leadgen'], columns=['month_payment'], values=['revenue']).reset_index()

    publisher   month_leadgen   revenue
month_payment            2019-01  2019-02  2019-03
0   facebook    2019-01  60.0     25.0     45.0
1   google      2019-02  NaN      85.0     90.0
2   google      2019-03  NaN      NaN      60.0
```

My expected output would be to sum on a running total by month. So for facebook I want to see 85.0 in the 2019-02 column (month 1 + month 2). Facebook's 2019-03 column would be 125.0 (month 1 + month 2 + month 3). Thank you.

Comment: Try: `df = df.pivot_table(index=['publisher', 'month_leadgen'], columns=['month_payment'], values=['revenue']).cumsum(axis=1).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try `.cumsum()` on axis=1. That is `cumsum(1)`.

```
df=df.join(df[['revenue']].cumsum(1).rename(columns=dict(revenue='Cumsum')))



publisher month_leadgen                     revenue                  Cumsum          \
month_payment                         2019-01 2019-02 2019-03   2019-01 2019-02   
0              facebook       2019-01    60.0    25.0    45.0    60.0    85.0   
1                google       2019-02     NaN    85.0    90.0     NaN    85.0   
2                google       2019-03     NaN     NaN    60.0     NaN     NaN   

                       
month_payment 2019-03  
0               130.0  
1               175.0  
2                60.0
```

Alternatively, do it at pivoting stage;

```
df2 = df=df.pivot_table(index=['month_leadgen','publisher'], columns=['month_payment'], values=['revenue']).cumsum(axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I need the cumsum for all months and all publishers. My real data has up to 9 months.

Comment: Why shouldnt it work with nine months? You can also try `df2 = df=df.pivot_table(index=['month_leadgen','publisher'], columns=['month_payment'], values=['revenue']).cumsum(axis=1).reset_index()
df2`

Comment: Ok, this last comment is great and its working. I can't thank you enough!! You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

just define your dataset this way with publisher as index:

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
'month_leadgen': ['2019-01', '2019-01', '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-02', '2019-03'],
'month_payment': ['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-03'],
'revenue': [60, 25, 45, 85, 90, 60]
},  index = ['facebook', 'facebook', 'facebook', 'google', 'google', 'google']
)

then execute execute this line:

df['TotalShifted'] = df.groupby(level=0)['revenue'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift(0))

you will obtain:

month_leadgen   month_payment   revenue TotalShifted
facebook    2019-01 2019-01 60  60
facebook    2019-01 2019-02 25  85
facebook    2019-01 2019-03 45  130
google  2019-02 2019-02 85  85
google  2019-02 2019-03 90  175
google  2019-03 2019-03 60  235

[image]